# Using a single formula to do a filter and subtotal in Excel

Tags: excel

this is my table

```
A        B       C
Mark     Usa     120.000
John     Germany  80.000
Frank    Usa      70.000
Mike     Italy    80.000
```

I would like to do a sub total only for 'Usa' people in a single formula.

Something like

```
=Subtotal(c1:c4;IF(B='USA'))
```

How to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C4,B1:B4,"USA")
```